# want to manipulate date command to count into future beyond today

Tags: linux, bash, date, unix

I have this snip of code I have been using in an alarm script I hacked together and have been using with success for the last year or so. But it has always been limited in the sense that if I specify an alarm duration that would extend beyond midnight, past 23:59, then the alarm simply sounds off immediately.

It has not been a problem b/c most of the time I just set an alarm for 1, 5, 10, 30 or 45 minutes as quick reminders. But now I would like to extend the functionality to extend beyond a day if needed and I am sure it is this snip of code that needs to be modified:

```
sleep $(( $(date --date="$at" +%s) - $(date +%s) ));
```

By first running:

```
15:10 ~ $ $(( $(date --date="23:59" +%s) - $(date +%s) )) ; date
bash: 31706: command not found
Sat Jul 12 15:10:34 ICT 2014
```

I see that there is 31706 seconds to go until 11:59PM. And then:

```
15:10 ~ $ $(( $(date --date="00:00" +%s) - $(date +%s) )) ; date
bash: -54637: command not found
Sat Jul 12 15:10:37 ICT 2014
```

I can see the code does not simply add an additional 1 second to the total number of seconds until midnight (tomorrow), but actually seems to count backwards to midnight that already occurred earlier today, some 15 odd hours ago.

I am unsure about the entire snip of code to be honest. What I wonder is if someone might mind breaking things down for a clearer understanding of what exactly is occurring here so I might be in a better position to modify my script so that it continues to count forward into the future, even beyond timestamps that will go beyond the current day.

Comment: Perhaps post the whole script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When only given time, that time is applied to the current date, so `00:00` refers to midnight of today's date, which has already transpired. To refer to midnight at the beginning of tomorrow's date, explicitly specify the date as `tomorrow`, i.e. the whole datetime as `tomorrow 00:00`:

```
$ date
Sat Jul 12 10:29:16 CEST 2014
$ date -d "00:00"
Sat Jul 12 00:00:00 CEST 2014
$ date -d "tomorrow 00:00"
Sun Jul 13 00:00:00 CEST 2014
```

Using that syntax, getting the number of seconds until midnight just works:

```
$ echo $(( $(date -d "tomorrow 00:00" +%s) - $(date +%s) ))
48527
```

Note: when run exactly at midnight, this code will print 86400, not 0.

Comment: @user...342: ok that was the ticket and the fix is in. I just a function to prepend $at with the word tomorrow if the duration of alarm time extends beyond 23:59 and it looks like it works. At least the alarm does not sound off immediately and it is still listed as a current process.